# Is it possible enable non-lion-style full-screen on OS X in Electron js?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I have a handy little program called iTerm (surely people know it here). There is a configuration option for OS X called "Use Lion-Style Fullscreen windows"

When this is disabled, it allows for behavior where a window will be full-screen without moving to a new "desktop".

[I've created a small demonstration for those who do not know what it looks like.](https://youtu.be/1P92Ny5NM-w).

My question is: is it possible to emulate this behavior in Electron js?

Answer (score 0):

Your demonstration doesn't works now, but by description I can offer one case which can be useful.
You should raise up level of window higher than 'main-menu' - `setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'main-menu', 1)`, activate `enableLargerThanScreen: true` and set size of window exactly like size of active window.

```js
import {
    BrowserWindow,
    screen
} from 'electron';

const fullScreenWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true,
    enableLargerThanScreen: true,
    frame: false,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    minimizable: false,
    movable: false
});

// Show it on primary or any another screen
const activeScreen = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();

fullScreenWindow.setResizable(true);
fullScreenWindow.setSize(activeScreen.size.width, activeScreen.size.height);
fullScreenWindow.setResizable(false);
fullScreenWindow.setPosition(activeScreen.bounds.x, activeScreen.bounds.y);

fullScreenWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'main-menu', 1);
fullScreenWindow.loadURL('file://app.html');
// or `fullScreenWindow.show()` instead of `fullScreenWindow.loadURL`
```

Created window overlaps main-menu and dock bar:

[image]